# Decreasing foam in over-carbonated beer

Tags: serving, carbonation, foam, head

I have some homebrew that is really over-carbonated (before i learned about [priming sugar calculators](https://www.google.com/search?q=priming%20sugar%20calculators)). Consequently, i have to pour it into two pint glasses to contain all the foam, and wait 5-10 minutes for the foam to settle out enough to actually drink it. The bottles are well-chilled first.

Is there something i can do when pouring it to *reduce* the head? I know some amount of head is desirable, but this is over the top (literally).

[Edit] I get this much foam despite pouring very slowly and carefully down the side of the glass.

Comment: Is this the right place for this question and not Homebrew SE?

Answer (score 4):

Soap is absolutely the worst thing you could do I guess :P.
Sometimes I notice that badly dried glasses (with soap rests) produce more foam...
In general, make sure your glass is spotlessly clean. You could then either leave it dry or make it a little wet, works sometimes...
Keep your glass diagonal to make sure the liquid touches the glass almost parallel to the glass' inner side.
Then when pouring, make sure you have a slow and fluent ray of beer that doesn't splash out of your bottle.

Answer (score -1):

This isn't the "best" answer but a dab of soap (think back to grade school science) with help break up the bubbles and bring that head down real fast